# Compare subfields in hamcrest

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

Is there a way to compare the value of a subfield with hamcrest?

```
class Obj{
    NestedObj nestedObj;
}

class NestedObj{
    String wantedProperty;
}
```

I have a `List<Obj>` objs, and I want to test that all `Objs` have a `wantedProperty` with value "wanted":

```
List<Obj> objs = new ArrayList<Obj>();

Obj obj = new Obj();
NestedObj nestedObj = new NestedObj();
nestedObj.setWantedProperty("wanted");
obj.setNestedObj(nestedObj);
objs.add(obj);

assertThat(objs, hasItems(Matchers.<Obj>hasProperty("nestedObj.wantedProperty", hasValue("wanted"))));
```

But nestedObj.wantedProperty do not works.

How can I get it work, if it is possible?

Comment: try something like this assertThat(objs, hasItems(Matchers.<Obj>hasProperty("nestedObj", Matchers.<NestedObj>hasProperty("wantedProperty",equalTo("wanted")))));

Comment: @user979349 Thank you man! It works :) Please add it as an answer to my question and I will upvote and accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this

```
assertThat(objs, hasItems(Matchers.<Obj>hasProperty("nestedObj", Matchers.<NestedObj>hasProperty("wantedProperty",equalTo("wanted")))));
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your desired functionality can be represented as follows

```
List<Obj> objs= .........; //get desired list
Matcher<NestedObj> nestedObjMatcher = hasProperty("wantedProperty", is("wanted"));
Matcher<Obj> objMatcher = hasProperty("nestedObj", nestedObjMatcher);
assertThat(objs, hasItem(objMatcher));
```

I am assuming here static imports of junit4 and similar with hamcrest Matcher.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have updated my answer giving more detail.  Your code have one error: The method assertThat(T, Matcher<? super T>) in the type MatcherAssert is not applicable for the arguments (List<Obj>, Matcher<Iterable<? super NestedObj>>). I have also found that method suggested in comment answer works. Anyway thank you, +1 for quick response :)

Comment: @mserioli yes that's true and thanks. Actually i have been following one junit guru from several months whose slides demonstrates advance features of junit4 and hamcrest library. I also checked after posting answer but i could not figure out why there was error in this piece of code.

Comment: @mserioli i have fixed error. Now i find that test are executing only on first object of objs list in both solution. can you verify. If that  persist we might need look on Parameterized test.

Comment: I think that it is a default behaviour of hasItems: Creates a matcher for Iterables that matches when consecutive passes over the examined Iterable yield at least one item that is matched by the corresponding matcher from the specified itemMatchers. Whilst matching, each traversal of the examined Iterable will stop as soon as a matching item is found. Do you know if there is something that tests that ALL items have a property? Thank you :)